# Ошибка 'str' object is not callable при написании кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

В строке widget.orientation(support) компилятор видит ошибку 'str' object is not callable
ВОПРОС: КАК БУДЕТ КОРРЕКТНЕЙ ЗАПИСАТЬ?
[image: Вот сам код]

Не обращайте особого внимания на качество написания я пробую для интереса
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в виде текста, а не в виде скриншота. Вы нам предлагаете с картинки перепечатать код, чтобы проверить его работспособность?

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что `widget.orientation` - это строка (`str`), эту строку нельзя вызывать как функцию. У вас там что-то другое видимо должно быть, не `orientation`.
Но если в `support` у вас тоже строка, может быть можно написать `widget.orientation = support`, но я не уверен.